# Why does POSIX restrict usleep argument to less than one million

Tags: c, posix, usleep

POSIX standard for [usleep](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/usleep.html) clearly states:

> The useconds argument shall be less than one million.

Why is it so?

Are there any known operating systems/libraries that actually enforce this restriction? Man pages for [Linux](https://linux.die.net/man/3/usleep), [macOS](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/usleep.3.html), [FreeBSD](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=usleep&sektion=3&apropos=0&manpath=freebsd) and [Solaris](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E53394_01/html/E54766/usleep-3c.html) does not mention this limitation.

Comment: [The Man](https://linux.die.net/man/3/usleep) does not report that limit. Maybe old doc at that link.

Comment: BTW the linked man reports _2004 Edition_. If you click on _A newer edition of this document exists [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/)_ the `usleep` function is not listed.

Comment: @LPs, yes, `usleep` was removed in [POSIX 1.2008](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/xrat/V4_xsh_chap01.html)

Comment: @LP, in your lined manpage the limit is well mentioned. `EINVAL` is returned if the parameter is not less than 1 million. Also the datatype `useconds_t` is mentioned to hold integer values in range [0,1000000].

Comment: @Gerhardh: it is mentioned with note "On systems where that is considered an error", and it is not stated that it *is* an error.

Comment: Interesting. My man page says: "The  type  useconds_t  is an unsigned integer type capable of holding integers in the range [0,1000000]". It looks like if the original meaning was that it shall not be a 16bit integer. However the exact wording causes that the type is not guaranteed to hold values larger than 1000000.